# SQL Annual and Quarterly INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a first ANNUAL table like

```
ID  |  Date     |  AField1  |  AField2
1a  | 21/8/2000  |  xxx      |  xxx  
1a  | 21/8/2001  |  xxx      |  xxx
1a  | 21/8/2002  |  xxx      |  xxx
...
1a  | 21/8/2013  |  xxx      |  xxx
1b  | 16/2/2000  |  xxx      |  xxx
1b  | 16/2/2001  |  xxx      |  xxx
...
```

and a second QUARTERLY table like

```
ID  |  Date     |  QField1  |  QField2
1a  | 1/1/2000  |  xxx      |  xxx  
1a  | 1/3/2000  |  xxx      |  xxx
1a  | 1/6/2000  |  xxx      |  xxx  
1a  | 1/9/2000  |  xxx      |  xxx
1a  | 1/1/2001  |  xxx      |  xxx  
1a  | 1/3/2001  |  xxx      |  xxx
...
1a  | 1/9/2013  |  xxx      |  xxx
1b  | 1/1/2000  |  xxx      |  xxx
1b  | 1/3/2000  |  xxx      |  xxx
...
```

**I am trying to write a query that would return info for each quarterly row and info from the last annual statement available corresponding to this quarter, for a given ID joining the two tables i.e:**

```
ID  |  AnnualDate  |  QuarterlyDate| AnnualField1  |  QuarteryField2 | ...
1a  | 21/8/1999     | 1/1/2000      |  xxx          |        xxx      | ...
1a  | 21/8/1999     | 1/3/2000      |  xxx          |        xxx      | ...
1a  | 21/8/1999     | 1/6/2000      |  xxx          |        xxx      | ...
1a  | 21/8/2000     | 1/9/2000      |  xxx          |        xxx      | ...
1a  | 21/8/2000     | 1/1/2001      |  xxx          |        xxx      | ...
1a  | 21/8/2000     | 1/3/2001      |  xxx          |        xxx      | ...
...
1a  | 21/8/2012     | 1/1/2013      |  xxx          |        xxx      | ...
1a  | 21/8/2012     | 1/3/2013      |  xxx          |        xxx      | ...
1a  | 21/8/2012     | 1/6/2013      |  xxx          |        xxx      | ...
1a  | 21/8/2013     | 1/9/2013      |  xxx          |        xxx      | ...
```

so far, my SQL query looks like:

```
SELECT    
      q.ID,
      q.Date,
      q.QField1,
      q.QField2,
      a.AField1, 
      a.AField2

FROM tableQ AS q INNER JOIN tableA AS a ON q.ID = a.ID

WHERE q.ID = ('678abc')

ORDER BY ID, Date DESC
```

but the date relation is obviously missing.. It might look simple but I have been stuck on this for more than 3 hours now and I would appreciate any help. I tried the SELECT TOP or MAX HAVING or INNER JOIN with q.Date >= a.Date but unsuccessfully...

**EDIT:** Also a basic inner join like:
    Year(q.Date) = Year(a.Date)
doesn't work as sometimes the last annual statement might be from the year before or even older.

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Quarterly.ID
      ,Quarterly.Date
      ,Quarterly.QField1
      ,Quarterly.QField2
      ,Annual.AField1
      ,Annual.AField2
FROM Quarterly
     LEFT JOIN Annual
         ON Quarterly.ID = Annual.ID
WHERE Annual.Date = (SELECT MAX(Annual2.Date) 
                     FROM Annual AS Annual2 
                     WHERE Annual2.ID = Quarterly.ID
                           AND Annual2.Date < Quarterly.Date)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try LEFT join like below:

```
SELECT    
      q.ID,
      q.Date,
      q.Field1,
      q.Field2,
      a.Field1, 
      a.Field2

FROM tableQ AS q LEFT JOIN tableA AS a 
ON q.ID = a.ID
AND a.Date = (SELECT MAX(Date) FROM tableA where ID = '678abc')
WHERE q.ID = ('678abc')
ORDER BY ID, Date DESC
```

Comment: my question is precisely how do you obtain the 'last annual statement date' for each quarterly row, ty for trying to help.

Comment: You can use a subquery to find the MAX date. Edited the answer.